# How can I prevent an event/method from being spammed, without allowing the client to alter it in any way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a form that calls a method which inserts a document into a collection when clicked. The issue here is that it can be spammed, and I want to know the best way to prevent that. I'm very well aware of what I can do client-side, but I'm worried about that they can just go edit the code in the browser (correct me if I'm wrong) and bypass that.

(client)

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'submit #myForm': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('myMethod', function(error, response) {
            //
        });
    },
});
```

(server)

```
Meteor.methods({
    myMethod: function() {
        try {
            return (Collection.insert({
                data: 'Hello world'
            })) ? true : false;
        } catch(e) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(e);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm probably making a fool out of myself now, but this really concerns me and I'd really like an answer. Thanks.

Comment: How about just filtering by IP the person who makes too many consequent requests (server-side, of course)?

Comment: Read about the ddp rate limiter [Package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ddp-rate-limiter) and [tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/rate-limiting-methods#!).